# Cannot login using flutter, redux and firebase-auth as described in FlutterByExample

Tags: redux, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have created an action as follows:

```
class EmailLogIn {
  EmailLogIn({this.email, this.password});
  String email;
  String password;
}
```

a reducer as follows:

```
FirebaseUser _emailLogIn(FirebaseUser user, action) {
  return action.user;
}
```

after following the flutter by example tutorial.

The middleware is executed but I get an error in the reducer. `action.user` getter is not recognised.

Please assist.

Also note: A similar question exists at [Flutter, Redux and Firebase Auth Invalid argument(s) error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55328348/10462168) and I was following the tutorial at [Flutter by example: LogIn Redux Cycle contd](https://flutterbyexample.com/log-in-redux-cycle-contd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it correct because the class EmailLogIn doesn't contain `user` attribute but it contains `email` and `password` when you do `action.user` getter is not recognized because `user` doesn't exist in the class,  if you take a look at FlutterByExample [code](https://github.com/ericwindmill/flutter_by_example_apps/blob/818cfa2e05abcf4527ca330dec3c4e595c881381/redux_app/lib/actions/auth_actions.dart#L9) the `LogInSuccessful` contains `final FirebaseUser user;` not  `email` and `password`!

Comment: Thanks for the response Taym. It set me in the right direction. My mistake was that I was including the `next(action);` code after the calling the LogInSuccessful action. In the updated code on github, this is clearly excluded which means that the auth reducer is not called after the middleware but a new dispatch of the action LogInSuccessful is called instead.